# Difference between selecting columns using data frame name and pl.col() in polars

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I'm relatively new to Polars. I have some doubts regarding its operations. I can perform an operation like this in Polars,

```
df = df.with_columns(((pl.col("netsales")/pl.col("sold_quantity")).alias("net_div"))
```

same can be achieved using,

```
df = df.with_columns((df["netsales"]/df["sold_quantity"]).alias("net_div"))
```

Is there any difference among them?,in terms of performance.

Also,

```
df = df.with_columns((df["netsales"]/df["sold_quantity"]).alias("net_mul"),
(df["netsales"]+df["sold_quantity"]).alias("net_add")
)
```

The above operation can be done individually like this,

```
df = df.with_columns((df["netsales"]/df["sold_quantity"]).alias("net_mul"))
df = df.with_columns((df["netsales"]+df["sold_quantity"]).alias("net_add"))
```

Is there any difference between the above two ways of performing the same operations in terms of performance? I couldn't find any answers or documentation regarding this online. I would appreciate your support if you could share some knowledge on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Let's start with this:

```
df = df.with_columns((df["netsales"]/df["sold_quantity"]).alias("net_div"))
```

Take a step back, what happens when you call `df["netsales"]`?

It extracts that column as a Series with the same name as the column. When you divide one Series by another it produces yet another Series with the per element quotient, as you'd expect.

What happens when you feed `with_columns` with a Series? It either adds a column or replaces an existing column with that data (assuming they're the same height).

Because of python's order of operations, python is going to resolve the Series division before polars knows what you're doing and so there's no way to insert a warning that you shouldn't do that.

### Why shouldn't you do that?

#### Performance experiment

###### Setup

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
df=pl.DataFrame({
    'a':np.random.normal(5,2,int(10e7)),
    'b':np.random.normal(5,2,int(10e7)),
    'c':np.random.normal(5,2,int(10e7)),
    'd':np.random.normal(5,2,int(10e7)),
    'e':np.random.normal(5,2,int(10e7))
    })
```

###### Test with square bracket notation

```
df.with_columns(df[x]**2.3 for x in df.columns)
# takes 7.9s and only uses one core
```

###### Test with expressions

```
df.with_columns(pl.col(x)**2.3 for x in df.columns)
# takes 2.2s and uses 5 cores, corresponding to 5 columns
```

Polars will automatically run all your expressions in parallel by default. When you use square bracket notation you're disallowing that from happening. The reason you're disallowing that from happening is python is going to resolve all the elements in the generator before it hands it off to `with_columns` and since python is inherently serial, that's what you get.

#### Ergonomics

In the expression case, you can just do

```
df.with_columns(pl.all()**2.3)
```

There are also a whole host of [column selectors](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html) to fine tune choosing columns.

Also, using expressions lets you chain together several `with_columns`, `filter`s, etc and the expressions are executed based on the context

for example you can't do this

```
(
    df
    .filter(pl.col('netsales')<1000)
    .with_columns(
        df["netsales"]/df["sold_quantity"]
        )
    )
```

because the `df["netsales"]` isn't aware of the filter so the sizes will be wrong.

With expressions, you can do

```
(
    df
    .filter(pl.col('netsales')<1000)
    .with_columns(pl.col("netsales")/pl.col("sold_quantity"))
    )
```

#### LazyFrames

With LazyFrames the data isn't tabulated yet so you can't use square bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

the `[` syntax won't work for lazyframes, you should prefer expression where possible