# Replacing values from a given column with the modified values from a different column in python-polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I need to update the values of a column (X) in correspondance with certain values ('v') of another column Y with values from another column (Z) times some numbers and then cast the obtained column to int:

In pandas the code is as follow:

```
df.loc[df["Y"] == "v", "X"] = (
        df.loc[df["Y"] == "v", "Z"] * 1.341 * 15).astype(int)
```

In polars i'm able to select values (e.g. nulls) from a column and replace them with values from another column:

```
df=df.with_columns(
    pl.when(df['col'].is_null())
        .then(df['other_col'])
            .otherwise(df['col'])
                .alias('alias_col')
)
```

but i'm stuck at nesting the call to the (modified) third column.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: It's much easier to help if you can include a small sample dataframe to make your example code runnable.

Comment: Please [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77764146/difference-between-selecting-columns-using-data-frame-name-and-pl-col-in-polar/77765916#77765916)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we create a dataframe to operate on. I inferred the context and types from your pandas example.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "X": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    "Y": ["w", "w", "v", "w", "v"],
    "Z": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
})
```

**Output.**

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ X   ┆ Y   ┆ Z   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ w   ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ w   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ v   ┆ 3   │
│ 1   ┆ w   ┆ 4   │
│ 1   ┆ v   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Then, it looks like you want to do the following

- When column `Y` is equal to `"v"`, then take the integer value of column `Z` times `3.41 x 15`.
- Otherwise, take the value of columns `X`.
- Store the result again in column `X`.

This can be achieved with polars' `when-then-otherwise` expression.

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.col("Y") == "v"
    ).then(
        (pl.col("Z") * 1.341 * 15).cast(pl.Int64)
    ).otherwise(
        pl.col("X")
    ).alias("X")
)
```

**Output.**

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ X   ┆ Y   ┆ Z   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ w   ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ w   ┆ 2   │
│ 60  ┆ v   ┆ 3   │
│ 1   ┆ w   ┆ 4   │
│ 100 ┆ v   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```