# How to create column based on other DataFrame row filter?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a LazyFrame called "hourly_data", which contains a hourly datetime column called "time".
I also have a DataFrame called "future_periods", which contains two datetime columns called "start", the start datetime of future periods, and "end", the end time of future periods. Importantly, these future periods are not overlapping.

I want to create a column called "period" for the hourly_data LazyFrame, which should have an int value based on for which period (which future_periods DataFrame row so going from 0 to 9 if there are 10 periods) the time column value of hourly_data is between the start and end column values of future_periods.

I tried to do the following:

```
periods = pl.Series(range(future_periods.height))
hourly_data = hourly_data.with_columns(
    (
        pl.when(((future_periods.get_column('start') <= pl.col('time')) & (pl.col('time') <= future_periods.get_column('end'))).any())
        .then(periods.filter(pl.Series((future_periods.get_column('start') <= pl.col('real_time')) & (pl.col('real_time') <= future_periods.get_column('end')))).to_list()[0])
        .otherwise(None)
    ).alias('period')
)
```

But this gave me the error: TypeError: Series constructor called with unsupported type 'Expr' for the `values` parameter

What I want to accomplish:
Input:

```
hourly_data:
┌────────────────────┐
│ time               │
│ ---                │
│ datetime           │
╞════════════════════╡
│ 2024-01-01 00:00:00│
│ 2024-01-01 01:00:00│
│ 2024-01-01 02:00:00│
│         ...        │
│ 2024-03-31 23:00:00│
│ 2024-04-01 00:00:00│
│ 2024-04-01 01:00:00│
│         ...        │
│ 2024-06-01 00:00:00│
└────────────────────┘
future_periods:
┌─────────────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ start                   ┆ end                   │
│ ---                     ┆ ---                   │
│ datetime                ┆ datetime              │
╞═════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ 2024-01-01 00:00:00     ┆ 2024-01-31 23:00:00   │
│ 2024-02-01 00:00:00     ┆ 2024-02-28 23:00:00   │
│ 2024-03-01 00:00:00     ┆ 2024-03-31 23:00:00   │
│ 2024-04-01 00:00:00     ┆ 2024-05-31 23:00:00   │
└─────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Output:

```
hourly_data:
┌─────────────────────────┬────────┐
│ time                    ┆ period │
│ ---                     ┆ ---    │
│ datetime                ┆ int    │
╞═════════════════════════╪════════╡
│ 2024-01-01 00:00:00     ┆ 0      │
│ 2024-01-01 01:00:00     ┆ 0      │
│ 2024-01-01 02:00:00     ┆ 0      │
│          ...            ┆ ...    │
│ 2024-03-31 23:00:00     ┆ 2      │
│ 2024-04-01 00:00:00     ┆ 3      │
│ 2024-04-01 01:00:00     ┆ 3      │
│          ...            ┆ ...    │
│ 2024-06-01 00:00:00     ┆ None   │
└─────────────────────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: The best way to get a good answer is to add some examples of input data and output data. Ideally, they should be as simple as possible but good enough to illustrate your point.

Comment: The error is because you're trying to mix the Series API and Expressions API: `pl.Series(future_periods.get_column('start') <= pl.col('real_time'))` - Expressions are "lazy" and need to be evaluated inside a Dataframe context, you cannot create a Series from them directly like that. `.get_column()` also returns a Series so you pretty much "never" want to use that. You can use `future_periods.lazy()` to get a LazyFrame so that you can `.join()` with `hourly_data` as shown by Roman.

Comment: A bit more on the difference between expressions and series... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77764146/difference-between-selecting-columns-using-data-frame-name-and-pl-col-in-polar/77765916#77765916

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it's inequality join, or in your case, join on range. Here's one way of doing this. Let's create some example data first:

```py
hourly_data = pl.DataFrame({
    "time": ['2023-01-01 14:00','2023-01-02 09:00', '2023-01-04 11:00']
}).lazy()

future_periods = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": [1,2,3,4],
    "start": ['2023-01-01 11:00','2023-01-02 10:00', '2023-01-03 15:00', '2023-01-04 10:00'],
    "end": ['2023-01-01 16:00','2023-01-02 11:00', '2023-01-03 18:00', '2023-01-04 15:00']
}).lazy()

┌──────────────────┬──────┐
│ time             ┆ data │
│ ---              ┆ ---  │
│ str              ┆ str  │
╞══════════════════╪══════╡
│ 2023-01-01 14:00 ┆ A    │
│ 2023-01-02 09:00 ┆ B    │
│ 2023-01-04 11:00 ┆ C    │
└──────────────────┴──────┘ 
┌─────┬──────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ start            ┆ end              │
│ --- ┆ ---              ┆ ---              │
│ i64 ┆ str              ┆ str              │
╞═════╪══════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2023-01-01 11:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 16:00 │
│ 2   ┆ 2023-01-02 10:00 ┆ 2023-01-02 11:00 │
│ 3   ┆ 2023-01-03 15:00 ┆ 2023-01-03 18:00 │
│ 4   ┆ 2023-01-04 10:00 ┆ 2023-01-04 15:00 │
└─────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Now, you can do it in two steps - first, calculate link between `time` and future period `id`:

```py
time_periods = (
   hourly_data
       .join(future_periods, how="cross")
       .filter(
           pl.col("time") > pl.col("start"),
           pl.col("time") < pl.col("end")
        ).select(["time","id"])
)

┌──────────────────┬─────┐
│ time             ┆ id  │
│ ---              ┆ --- │
│ str              ┆ i64 │
╞══════════════════╪═════╡
│ 2023-01-01 14:00 ┆ 1   │
│ 2023-01-04 11:00 ┆ 4   │
└──────────────────┴─────┘
```

And then you can join it with original dataframe:

```py
hourly_data.join(time_periods, how="left", on="time").collect()

┌──────────────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ time             ┆ data ┆ id   │
│ ---              ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str              ┆ str  ┆ i64  │
╞══════════════════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 2023-01-01 14:00 ┆ A    ┆ 1    │
│ 2023-01-02 09:00 ┆ B    ┆ null │
│ 2023-01-04 11:00 ┆ C    ┆ 4    │
└──────────────────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Another way of doing this might be using [`duckdb`](https://pypi.org/project/duckdb/) thanks to [`integraion with polars`](https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/python/polars.html):

```py
import duckdb
import polars as pl

duckdb.sql("""
    select
        h.time, h.data, p.id
    from hourly_data as h
        left join future_periods as p on
            p.start < h.time and
            p.end > h.time
""").pl()

┌──────────────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ time             ┆ data ┆ id   │
│ ---              ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str              ┆ str  ┆ i64  │
╞══════════════════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 2023-01-01 14:00 ┆ A    ┆ 1    │
│ 2023-01-04 11:00 ┆ C    ┆ 4    │
│ 2023-01-02 09:00 ┆ B    ┆ null │
└──────────────────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a [.join_asof](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.join_asof.html) to best align the bins to your hourly `'time'` onto the future_periods `'start'`. Then you can null-out any ids whose hourly `'time'` is outside of the joined `'start'` and `'end'` times.

```py
from polars import col
import polars as pl

hourly_data = pl.DataFrame({
    "time": ['2023-01-01 14:00','2023-01-02 09:00', '2023-01-04 11:00']
}).with_columns(col(pl.String).str.to_datetime()).lazy()

future_periods = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": [1,2,3,4],
    "start": ['2023-01-01 11:00','2023-01-02 10:00', '2023-01-03 15:00', '2023-01-04 10:00'],
    "end": ['2023-01-01 16:00','2023-01-02 11:00', '2023-01-03 18:00', '2023-01-04 15:00']
}).with_columns(col(pl.String).str.to_datetime()).lazy()

print(
    hourly_data.sort('time')
    .join_asof(future_periods.sort('start'), left_on='time', right_on='start')
    .select(
        pl.col('time'),
        (
            pl.when(pl.col('time').is_between(pl.col('start'), pl.col('end')))
            .then(pl.col('id'))
        )
    )
    .collect()
)
# shape: (3, 2)
# ┌──────────────────┬──────┐
# │ time             ┆ id   │
# │ ---              ┆ ---  │
# │ str              ┆ i64  │
# ╞══════════════════╪══════╡
# │ 2023-01-01 14:00 ┆ 1    │
# │ 2023-01-02 09:00 ┆ null │
# │ 2023-01-04 11:00 ┆ 4    │
# └──────────────────┴──────┘
```

If you're unfamiliar with this type of join, I'd recommend commenting out the `select` portion of my code to see the raw result of the join.