How to join two polars dataframe with multiple types of conditions? (Equalities and Comparisons)
I'm trying to translate an SQL query into a polars code, and I'm stuck at one line of query, which basically join two tables with certain conditions, here is the sample SQL query that I have been working on:
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 as tab1
LEFT JOIN table_2 as tab2
ON tab1.article_no = tab2.article_no -- condition 1
   AND DIV(tab1.variant_no, 1000) = tab2.variant_no -- condition 2
   AND tab1.date_of_day BETWEEN tab2.date_from AND tab2.date_to -- condition 3

So here when doing the LEFT JOIN, There are three conditions, out of which two are equality checks and one is checking whether date_of_day lies in between the other two date columns from table_2.
In polars, when you have to join two dataframes/lazyframes you have to use either tab_1.join(tab_2, on=[certain_column]) or tab_1.join(tab_2, left_on=[certain_column], right_on=[certain_column]).
We can't use on= and [left_on, right_on] together, but in this case, I can't put all the three conditions either inside the on= or the left_on, right_on, so I'm not sure how can I possibly achieve this.
Although I tried doing the date comparison separately after joining with the first two conditions:
table_1 = pl.read_csv('table_1.csv')
table_2 = pl.read_csv('table_2.csv')

table_joined = (
    table_1
    .join(
        table_2, 
        how='left', 
        left_on=[pl.col('article_no', pl.col('variant_no')//1000)],  #Giving first two conditions in join
        right_on=[pl.col('article_no'), pl.col('variant_no')], 
        suffix="_tab2"
    )
)

columns_to_check = ['price_1', 'price_2', 'price_3']

final_df = (
    table_joined
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.when(
                (pl.col('date_of_day').ge(pl.col('date_from'))) &   # giving the third condition after joining, and converting the other columns to None since it's a left join
                (pl.col('date_of_day').le(pl.col('date_to')))
            ).then(pl.col(col)).otherwise(None).alias(col)
            for col in columns_to_check   # using for loop to convert other columns to None (Null)
        ]
    )
)

Although this technique is working fine, but it takes a lot of memory when working with millions of rows, also it's not very consistent way of joining (because sometimes there are more than expected rows in the final dataframe). I tried looking online for ways to give multiple types of conditions, but haven't found any such examples.
I need to apply all the three conditions during the left join itself, to avoid such walkthrough and memory consumptions.
Can somebody help me out here. Thanks in advance.
Edit -
Below is a sample data and code:
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

table_1_data = {
    "article_no": [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008],
    "variant_no": [5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 6000, 4000, 6000],
    "date_of_day": [date(2023, 1, 2), date(2023, 1, 12), date(2023, 1, 15), date(2023, 2, 5), date(2023, 3, 15), date(2023, 1, 2), date(2023, 1, 12), date(2023, 1, 15)],
    "quantity": [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 45, 50, 60]
}

table_1 = pl.DataFrame(table_1_data)

table_2_data = {
    "article_no": [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1006],
    "variant_no": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    "date_from": [date(2023, 1, 1), date(2023, 1, 10), date(2023, 1, 1), date(2023, 1, 1), date(2023, 3, 1)],
    "date_to": [date(2023, 2, 1), date(2023, 1, 15), date(2023, 1, 10), date(2023, 1, 15), date(2023, 3, 31)],
    "price": [100, 110, 120, 130, 140]
}

table_2 = pl.DataFrame(table_2_data)

# Print sample data
print("Table 1:")
print(table_1)
print("\nTable 2:")
print(table_2)

joined_table = (
    table_1
    .join(table_2, 
          how='left', 
          left_on=[pl.col('article_no'), pl.col('variant_no')//1000],
          right_on=[pl.col('article_no'), pl.col('variant_no')],
          suffix='_tab2'
    )
    .select('article_no', 'variant_no', 'date_of_day', 'quantity', 'price')
)

print('\nJoined Table:')
print(joined_table)

exptected = {
    "article_no": [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008],
    "variant_no": [5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 6000, 4000, 6000],
    "date_of_day": [date(2023, 1, 2), date(2023, 1, 12), date(2023, 1, 15), date(2023, 2, 5), date(2023, 3, 15), date(2023, 1, 2), date(2023, 1, 12), date(2023, 1, 15)],
    "quantity": [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 45, 50, 60],
    "price": [100, 110, None, None, None, None, None, None]
}

exptected = pl.DataFrame(exptected)

print('\nExpected Output:')
print(exptected)

The output for this code is:
Table 1:
shape: (8, 4)
┌────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ article_no ┆ variant_no ┆ date_of_day ┆ quantity │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---      │
│ i64        ┆ i64        ┆ date        ┆ i64      │
╞════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╡
│ 1001       ┆ 5000       ┆ 2023-01-02  ┆ 10       │
│ 1002       ┆ 6000       ┆ 2023-01-12  ┆ 15       │
│ 1003       ┆ 7000       ┆ 2023-01-15  ┆ 20       │
│ 1004       ┆ 8000       ┆ 2023-02-05  ┆ 25       │
│ 1005       ┆ 9000       ┆ 2023-03-15  ┆ 30       │
│ 1006       ┆ 6000       ┆ 2023-01-02  ┆ 45       │
│ 1007       ┆ 4000       ┆ 2023-01-12  ┆ 50       │
│ 1008       ┆ 6000       ┆ 2023-01-15  ┆ 60       │
└────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘

Table 2:
shape: (5, 5)
┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ article_no ┆ variant_no ┆ date_from  ┆ date_to    ┆ price │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ i64        ┆ i64        ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ 1001       ┆ 5          ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 2023-02-01 ┆ 100   │
│ 1002       ┆ 6          ┆ 2023-01-10 ┆ 2023-01-15 ┆ 110   │
│ 1003       ┆ 7          ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 2023-01-10 ┆ 120   │
│ 1004       ┆ 8          ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 2023-01-15 ┆ 130   │
│ 1006       ┆ 9          ┆ 2023-03-01 ┆ 2023-03-31 ┆ 140   │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────┘

Joined Table:
shape: (8, 5)
┌────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ article_no ┆ variant_no ┆ date_of_day ┆ quantity ┆ price │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ i64        ┆ i64        ┆ date        ┆ i64      ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ 1001       ┆ 5000       ┆ 2023-01-02  ┆ 10       ┆ 100   │
│ 1002       ┆ 6000       ┆ 2023-01-12  ┆ 15       ┆ 110   │
│ 1003       ┆ 7000       ┆ 2023-01-15  ┆ 20       ┆ 120   │
│ 1004       ┆ 8000       ┆ 2023-02-05  ┆ 25       ┆ 130   │
│ 1005       ┆ 9000       ┆ 2023-03-15  ┆ 30       ┆ null  │
│ 1006       ┆ 6000       ┆ 2023-01-02  ┆ 45       ┆ null  │
│ 1007       ┆ 4000       ┆ 2023-01-12  ┆ 50       ┆ null  │
│ 1008       ┆ 6000       ┆ 2023-01-15  ┆ 60       ┆ null  │
└────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┴───────┘

Expected Output:
shape: (8, 5)
┌────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ article_no ┆ variant_no ┆ date_of_day ┆ quantity ┆ price │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ i64        ┆ i64        ┆ date        ┆ i64      ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ 1001       ┆ 5000       ┆ 2023-01-02  ┆ 10       ┆ 100   │
│ 1002       ┆ 6000       ┆ 2023-01-12  ┆ 15       ┆ 110   │
│ 1003       ┆ 7000       ┆ 2023-01-15  ┆ 20       ┆ null  │
│ 1004       ┆ 8000       ┆ 2023-02-05  ┆ 25       ┆ null  │
│ 1005       ┆ 9000       ┆ 2023-03-15  ┆ 30       ┆ null  │
│ 1006       ┆ 6000       ┆ 2023-01-02  ┆ 45       ┆ null  │
│ 1007       ┆ 4000       ┆ 2023-01-12  ┆ 50       ┆ null  │
│ 1008       ┆ 6000       ┆ 2023-01-15  ┆ 60       ┆ null  │
└────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┴───────┘



here in the output, the row number 3 and 4 doesn't satisfy the third condition that is date_from <= date_of_day <= date_to, so the columns from table_2 should be Null.

Can you post small sample csv files and expected output? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Polars does not yet support BETWEEN joins. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10068

Hi @Dogbert, I have edited my question with sample code, output, and expected output as well, thanks.

Per the update: you can add the nulling out after the join to get the expected output e.g. pl.when(pl.col("date_of_day").is_between("date_from", "date_to")).then(pl.col("date_from", "date_to", "price")) - but this is essentially what your initial example is already doing.

Until Polars adds proper non-equi join support, the general recommendation is to use an alternative tool e.g duckdb - which can convert to/from Polars dataframes easily. See the second example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77885953/

Thanks @jqurious, looks like duckdb will be a good alternative, I just hope it will not crash when handling large data. I looked up to their official website, they claim it can process larger-than-memory workloads.

In polars, we have join_asof which is very similar to left join.
result = (
    table_1.lazy()
    .join(
        table_2.lazy(),
        how="left",
        left_on="article_no",
        right_on="article_no"
    )
    .filter(
        (pl.col("variant_no") // 1000 == pl.col("variant_no_right")) &
        (pl.col("date_of_day") >= pl.col("date_from")) &
        (pl.col("date_of_day") <= pl.col("date_to"))
    )
    .with_columns([
        pl.when(pl.col("date_to").is_null())
        .then(None)
        .otherwise(pl.col("price"))
        .alias("price")
    ])
    .collect()
)

Please refer to the below sample code with sample data,
import polars as pl
from datetime import date


table_1_data = {
    "article_no": [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005],
    "variant_no": [5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000],
    "date_of_day": [date(2023, 1, 2), date(2023, 1, 12), date(2023, 1, 15), date(2023, 2, 5), date(2023, 3, 15)],
    "quantity": [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
}

table_1 = pl.DataFrame(table_1_data)

table_2_data = {
    "article_no": [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1006],
    "variant_no": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    "date_from": [date(2023, 1, 1), date(2023, 1, 10), date(2023, 1, 1), date(2023, 2, 1), date(2023, 3, 1)],
    "date_to": [date(2023, 2, 1), date(2023, 1, 15), date(2023, 2, 1), date(2023, 2, 15), date(2023, 3, 31)],
    "price": [100, 110, 120, 130, 140]
}

table_2 = pl.DataFrame(table_2_data)

# Print sample data
print("Table 1:")
print(table_1)
print("\nTable 2:")
print(table_2)

result = (
    table_1.lazy()
    .join(
        table_2.lazy(),
        how="left",
        left_on="article_no",
        right_on="article_no"
    )
    .filter(
        (pl.col("variant_no") // 1000 == pl.col("variant_no_right")) &
        (pl.col("date_of_day") >= pl.col("date_from")) &
        (pl.col("date_of_day") <= pl.col("date_to"))
    )
    .with_columns([
        pl.when(pl.col("date_to").is_null())
        .then(None)
        .otherwise(pl.col("price"))
        .alias("price")
    ])
    .collect()
)
print("\nJoin Result:")
print(result)

Updated code as per updated expected output in the question,
joined_table = (
    table_1
    .join(
        table_2,
        how='left',
        left_on=[pl.col('article_no'), pl.col('variant_no')//1000],
        right_on=[pl.col('article_no'), pl.col('variant_no')]
    )
    .with_columns([
        pl.when(
            (pl.col('date_of_day') >= pl.col('date_from')) &
            (pl.col('date_of_day') <= pl.col('date_to'))
        ).then(pl.col('price')).otherwise(None).alias('price')
    ])
    .select('article_no', 'variant_no', 'date_of_day', 'quantity', 'price')
)


Correct me if I'm wrong, but if we use .filter(), then it will basically remove the rows which doesn't match with the conditions, instead of nullifying them. But if the .join_asof() retains the rows which don't match with the conditions, then it's worth a try.

I could see 3 conditions in your select sql query, the left join acts more like an inner join if it satisfies all 3 conditions. could you share sample input and desired output?

Did it worked? any update?

Thank you for this, I have edited my question with sample code, output and expected output as well. Please check

Updated my answer, check and accept if you like

Thanks, it worked. Since I had multiple columns to nullify and not just one price column, I used .then(pl.col('price_1', 'price_2', 'price_3').otherwise(None)
