# Polars alternative solution to using map_groups with with_columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars

I think after the recent update of Polars (version 0.20.7), it stopped supporting the use of **map_groups** with **with_columns**
I got a Type Error stating

```
TypeError: cannot call `map_groups` when grouping by an expression
```

I am trying to Group By a column called Product Number and fill the null values using backward strategy for this Group By.

The code I wrote was.

```
df1 = (
    df1
    .group_by(['Product Number'])
    .map_groups(lambda df1: (
        df1
        .with_columns(
            df1['New Date'].fill_null(strategy='backward').alias('New Date1')
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Is there alternate solution which supports grouping with **with_columns** ?

Comment: side-note: same thing functionality-wise, but you may prefer [`.backward_fill()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.backward_fill.html#polars.Expr.backward_fill) instead of the `.fill_null`

Comment: **Note.** You should always try to avoid the `map_elements`/`map_batches`/`map_groups` family of functions. It'll usually be faster to rely polars' native expressions API. The documentation for any of the aforementioned will also provide a warning on this.

Comment: @Hericks. Using your solution over `map_groups` definitely made it faster. Will keep this in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you can use [pl.Expr.over](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.over.html) to compute expressions over certain groups.

```py
(
    df1
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("New Date")
        .fill_null(strategy="backward")
        .over("'Product Number'")
        .alias("New Date1")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Quick Fix

Just take out the brackets and do

```
(
    df1
    .group_by('Product Number')
    .map_groups(lambda df1: (
        df1
        .with_columns(
            pl.col('New Date')
            .fill_null(strategy='backward').alias('New Date1'))
        ))
)
```

### Root Cause

The new version 0.20.7 has [this PR](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/14071) which lets `group_by` accept unlimited `*args` and `**kwargs` without needing to use lists. This is how most other methods work (`select`, `with_columns`, `agg`, `over`, etc). Previous to this PR, `map_groups` still had the restriction that you could only make groups from the string name of columns. That is still the case but because of the change, the function sees `self.by=(['Product Number'])` and then when it does:

```
if not all(isinstance(c, str) for c in self.by):
    msg = "cannot call `map_groups` when grouping by an expression"
    raise TypeError(msg)
```

it doesn't check for and unpackage lists so it mistakenly raises as it wants to see nothing but strings. That's why the fix is to just remove the brackets.

There is [another PR](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/14099) that removes the restriction on `map_groups` that would, in the process, fix this bug. Hopefully it's merged for 0.20.8.

### Disclaimer:

I agree with Hericks that this is not a good use case for `map_groups`, this is just an explanation of the question asked about the emergent bug.

Also, as an aside, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77765916/1818713) on why you shouldn't use the pandas like syntax of referring to columns using the df name with square brackets inside of a context (`with_columns`, `select`, etc)

Comment: This issue occurred after the 0.20.7 update and your explanation gives more clarity as to why it was caused. `map_groups` also increases the execution time significantly. Hence it is ideal to avoid it most cases. Appreciate your detailed explanation to this error!

Comment: Thanks for also providing a separate fix for the root cause!